# spark total cpu and mem configuration per worker per hours

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

We are using `hadoop-2.7.3`
and `spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz`

We would like to run `spark` in cluster mode over `yarn`

I would like to schedule different cpu/mem for time of day so that it won't interfere with daily activities. 
i.e

```
after 8:00am use 2 cpus max (1 per job) 5 gb RAM max
after 17:00 use 8 cpus max and 16 gb max per job
```

Comment: Are you planning to resize the cluster?If not you can simply launch an application with the above resources possibly making use of scheduledExecutor on jvm if required.Additionally you may also want to explore dynamic resource allocation.https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation